# Folder share from windows 10 to ubuntu 20-04 - mount-error-13

Tags: windows-10, mount, passwords, shared-folders, ubuntu-20.04

My apologies in advance if this sounds like a really daft question but I don't even know where I am going wrong here is my situation:

I have 2 laptops at home connected to the same wifi network and I have a folder on my Windows 10 laptop that I want to share with another laptop running on Ubuntu 20.04

When I installed my Windows 10, I used my outlook account (say abc@outlook.com and outlook password) to setup windows. I have not setup any other password except for a PIN which I now use to get into windows. My outlook account has 2 step verification.

I have set my network settings to "Turn on network discovery" and "Turn on file and printer sharing"

I right click the folder I want to share (lets call it Education) and in advanced settings allow for it to be shared, grant full access to Everyone group and ensure that Everyone group is added in the security tab as well with full access

On my Ubuntu 20.04 I have created a folder on desktop named "Share" hence it is different from the name "Education" on the windows.

CIFS is installed on Ubuntu and I use the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.xxx/Education /home/xxxx/Desktop/Share -o user=abc@outlook.com
```

It asks me for a password which I am giving as my email password (and tried it with PIN as well)
The final output that I get in every case is:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

Here is what my problems are:

A) I never entered any separate or different password at the time of windows setup so I am assuming that my email password is now my windows password however I can not find any information on this online. I have tried with PIN as well but it doesn't work. Not sure if the issue I am getting is because of 2 factor authorisation or if I am using wrong windows password?

B) If I am supposed to use email password and 2 factor authorisation is not a problem then what can I do as next steps? I have gone through a lot of posts and tried almost all of them but they have left me confused and without any resolution. Can you please give me step by step guidance on what I can do next? Even if it is a link to a website which has a sure shot solution for this to work as every webpage is guiding to do it in a different way.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Linux does not support the Microsoft Account or Outlook user names,
so it cannot pass them to Windows.

Your options are:

- Give access to Everyone on the network share *and* its folder
  and don't use passwords
- Use a local Windows account for login rather than a Microsoft Account.

For more information and tips see
[How to mount remote Windows shares](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares).

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps explained [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-share-files-between-ubuntu-and-windows-10/) but when entering, from ubuntu, user and password (of windows user) to access shared windows folder, ubuntu kept looping asking credentials againg and again. After switching to a local account in windows, ubuntu asked credentials only once.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).